# Android data binding : Cannot find setter for attribute app:list

Tags: android, listview, android-databinding

This is my listView

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/productListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:list="@{page.results}"/>
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:list' with parameter type java.util.List on android.widget.ListView.
>   loc:33:20 - 33:31
>   ****\ data binding error ****

This is my BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:list"})
public static void bindList(Context context, ListView view, ObservableArrayList<Result> list) {
    ProductsAdapter arrayAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(context,list);
    view.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Can someone please help with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should leave the *bind* namespace out. Only `@BindingAdapter("list")` should suffice.

Additionally you don't need the `Context` parameter should use `List<Result>` instead of `ObservableArrayList<Result>`

```
@BindingAdapter("list")
public static void bindList(ListView view, List<Result> list) {
    Context context = view.getContext();
    view.setAdapter(new ProductsAdapter(context, list));
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It still gives the same error.

Comment: You might need to use `List` instead of `ObservableArrayList`.